# -[__NSArrayI length]: crash when trying to filter with searchController

Tags: ios, nsarray, uisearchdisplaycontroller, searchbar

I'm trying to filter with searchController. I am getting a crash (`-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`) at line `NSRange productNameRange = NSMakeRange(0, [[_list valueForKey:@"name"] length]);` in the following code:

```
-(void)updateFilteredContent:(NSString*)searchText {
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSLog(@"_categories are %@",_categories);
    for (NSDictionary *object in _categories) {
        NSUInteger searchOptions = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch;
        NSRange productNameRange = NSMakeRange(0, [[_list valueForKey:@"name"] length]);
        NSRange foundRange = [[_list valueForKey:@"name"] rangeOfString:searchText options:searchOptions range:productNameRange];
        if (foundRange.length > 0) {
            [self.searchResults addObject:object];
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adding an if statement on the length like `if ([[object valueForKey:@"name"] length] >0){` but it still crashing.

an example of the log for _list is:

```
_list names are (
    "Honda",
    "Ford",
    Toyota,
```

Comment: What do you think `[_list valueForKey:@"name"]` returns?

Comment: by returns, do you mean the type of class?

Comment: valueForKey: returns array... [[_list valueForKey:@"name"][0] length ]; try like this..

Comment: if([_list valueForKey:@"name"].count == 0) return; put this line before the above line

Comment: that was it TamilKing, adding [0] at the end fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your [_list valueForKey:@"name"] returns an NSarray, which should be an NSString to calculate length of it..

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this condition and let me know if it still crashes!

```
if([_list allkeys] contains @"name"])
{
  NSString *tempStr = [_list valueForKey:@"name"];
}
if(tempStr)

NSRange productNameRange = NSMakeRange(0, [tempStr length]);
```